# Alfresco OAuth authentication Vs Alfresco Ticket Authentication

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I have requirement on authenticating and authorization the users sending request to Alfresco repository for CRUD operation. I am confused with which approach to use ...either 0Auth or Alfresco ticket. Can anyone suggest

Comment: Here user would be accessing the Alfresco repository via API

Answer (score 1):

I'm using only the community version, but I think is better to use the ticket, sending a post request to "/tickets" providing the "UserId" and "password" in jSON.

You'll receive, if login succefuly, the ticket to use as your Authorization, instead of the Basic Auth, for example.